# Hover an element and then click not working

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, protractor

This question has been asked before, but I have a more specific spin on it.  I have an `<article>` element that has the style `visibility:hidden` by default.  I use a pseudo selector `&:hover` to change the visibility to 'visible'.

In my protractor test, I move the mouse to the article as if to hover, I assert that the visibility is in fact visible, and then I perform a click on the article.

The article never seems to receive the click, and I can't write the subsequent tests for the functionality of the item.

//code to test that the hover works (this is successful)

```
        it('the button to launch the action menu should become visible when it is hovered over', function () {
            ptor.actions()
                .mouseMove(element.all(by.css('article.asset-action')).get(0))
                .perform();

            var art = element.all(by.css('article.asset-action')).get(0);
            art.getCssValue('visibility')
                .then(function(val) {
                    console.log('visibility value is: ' + val);
                    expect(val).toBe('visible');
                });
        });
```

//this is not successful, because click doesn't seem to fire

```
       it('clicking the article that brings up the asset action menu should also add a cover div to the DOM', function () {
            ptor.actions()
                .mouseMove(element.all(by.css('article.asset-action')).get(0))
                .perform();

            element.all(by.css('article.asset-action')).get(0)
                .then(function(art) {
                    art.click();
                });

            element(by.css('div.asset-action-pop-cover'))
                .then(function(cover) {
                    expect(browser.isElementPresent(cover)).toBe(true);
                });
        });
```

Another thing I noticed is that if I pause the test using ptor.sleep or set a breakpoint in code and switch over to Chrome, I can interact with several other element with the mouse, but I cannot click the item in question with the mouse, even when it is visible.  This is not the case when I run the app normally.

Comment: Can you please try this ?
browser.driver.executeScript('$(\'article.asset-action\').css(\'visibility\', \'visible\')'); and then click

Comment: @originof I ran it, and then performed the click, but the result is still the same, no clicking seems to take place.  Thanks for the lesson on how to execute scripts, though.

Comment: Was to exclude a problem with the hover event.

Comment: What event is binded to the article click ?

Comment: @originof it has an ng-click="myFunc($event)" binding